# How to use a eclipse to create a project to write the JSP?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a question about the eclipse. I want to write JSP by using eclipse. However, I don't know how to create a project and the .jsp file. Can anyone teach me how to write the jsp in eclipse. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tutorial for beginner](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are beginner, then I think it's better to write your first JSP page in Tomcat. After, you get enough experience of creating JSP page in Tomcat, or any other web server, then you should go with eclipse. This will help you cover your lots of basics.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have enough experience about JSP, but I don't know "how to use eclipse" to do that. Thank you.